# byte[] linked list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list, byte

i am trying to create a linked list witch contains byte arrays:

```
static Queue<byte[]> q = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
static byte buf[] = new byte[1024];

static void queueInit() throws IOException{
    ByteArrayInputStream bis= new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
    DataInputStream ois= new DataInputStream(bis);

    RandomAccessFile MyFile = new RandomAccessFile ("keys", "rw");
    for(int r=0;r<90;r++){
        MyFile.seek(r*1024);
        MyFile.read(buf);
        q.add(buf);
    }
    MyFile.close();
}
```

the problem is at commant q.add(buf);. The buffer is loaded with the correct bytes but the list is loading zeros.Any help?:)

Comment: Are you sure its not just everything but the first byte that is zeros.

Comment: Avoid reinventing the wheel. http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TByteArrayList.html

Answer (score 1):

No, your `LinkedList` will just have several references to the *same* array. You're only ever creating one byte array - and then reading data into it from the file time after time.

It's not clear why you've declared `buf` as a static variable at all, but you need to create a *new* array for each element in your list:

```
for (int r=0;r<90;r++) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    MyFile.seek(r * 1024);
    MyFile.read(buf);
    q.add(buf);
}
```

Also note that you're ignoring the return value of `read()`, which indicates how many bytes have been read. You might not have completely read 1024 bytes... what do you want to do in that case?

(Also, why bother seeking, or indeed using a `RandomAccessFile`? If you want to read the first 90K in 1K chunks, you can do that sequentially, with no seeking at all.)

Answer (score 0):

Every member of your queue is the same byte[] arrray.

When you call `q.add(buf)`, you're adding the reference `buf` to the queue -- not a copy of the array. Since the reference never changes, your queue is filled with multiple copies of the reference `buf`, all pointing to the same array.

It's possible that the end of your file contains a buffer full of '\0' bytes.

Try moving this into your loop:

```
byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same array instance for each entry in the LinkedList. That means that each call to MyFile.read(buf) will change the contents of all of your LinkedList entries. You should create a new byte[] for each entry you intend to add to the linked list.